# I need help on my C++ assignment using Microsoft Visual C++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Ok, so I don't want you to do my homework for me, but I'm a little lost with this final assignment and need all the help I can get. Learning about programming is tough enough, but doing it online is next to impossible for me... Now, to get to the program, I am going to paste what I have so far. This includes mostly //comments and what I have written so far. If you can help me figure out where all the errors are and how to complete the assignment, I will really appreciate it. Like I said, I don't want you to do my homework for me (it's my final), but any constructive criticism is welcome. This is my final assignment for this class and it is due tomorrow (Sunday before midnight, Arizona time).

***This is the assignment:***

Examine the following situation:

- Your company, Datamax, Inc., is in the process of automating its payroll systems. Your manager has asked you to create a program that calculates overtime pay for all employees. Your program must take into account the employee’s salary, total hours worked, and hours worked more than 40 in a week, and then provide an output that is useful and easily understood by company management.
- Compile your program utilizing the following background information and the code outline in Appendix D (included in the code section).
- Submit your project as an attachment including the code and the output.

Company Background:

- Three employees: Mark, John, and Mary
- The end user needs to be prompted for three specific pieces of input—name, hours worked, and hourly wage.
- Calculate overtime if input is greater than 40 hours per week.
- Provide six test plans to verify the logic within the program.
- Plan 1 must display the proper information for employee #1 with overtime pay.
- Plan 2 must display the proper information for employee #1 with no overtime pay.
- Plans 3-6 are duplicates of plan 1 and 2 but for the other employees.

Program Requirements:

- Define a base class to use for the entire program.
- The class holds the function calls and the variables related to the overtime pay calculations.
- Define one object per employee. Note there will be three employees.
- Your program must take the objects created and implement calculations based on total salaries, total hours, and the total number of overtime hours. See the Employee Summary Data section of the sample output.

Logic Steps to Complete Your Program:

- Define your base class.
- Define your objects from your base class.
- Prompt for user input, updating your object classes for all three users.
- Implement your overtime pay calculations.
- Display overtime or regular time pay calculations. See the sample output below.
- Implement object calculations by summarizing your employee objects and display the summary information in the example below.

***And this is the code:***

```
    // Final_Project.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
    //

    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <string>
    #include <iomanip>

    using namespace std;

    //
    //CLASS DECLARATION SECTION
    //
    class CEmployee
    { 
    public:
     void ImplementCalculations(string EmployeeName, double hours, double wage);
     void DisplayEmployInformation(void);
     void Addsomethingup (CEmployee, CEmployee, CEmployee);
     string EmployeeName ;
     int hours ;
        int overtime_hours ;
     int iTotal_hours ;
     int iTotal_OvertimeHours ;
     float wage ;
     float basepay ;
     float overtime_pay ;
     float overtime_extra ;
     float iTotal_salaries ;
     float iIndividualSalary ;
    };

    int main()
    { system("cls"); 

     cout << "Welcome to the Employee Pay Center";

    /*
    Use this section to define your objects.  You will have one object per employee.  You have only three employees.
    The format is your class name and your object name.
    */


     std::cout << "Please enter Employee's Name: ";
     std::cin >> EmployeeName;
     std::cout << "Please enter Total Hours for (EmployeeName): ";
     std::cin >> hours;
     std::cout << "Please enter Base Pay for(EmployeeName): ";
     std::cin >> basepay;
    /*
    Here you will prompt for the first employee’s information.
    Prompt the employee name, hours worked, and the hourly wage.  For each piece of information, you will update the appropriate class member defined above.
    Example of Prompts
    Enter the employee name      = 
    Enter the hours worked       = 
    Enter his or her hourly wage = 
    */

    /*
    Here you will prompt for the second employee’s information.
    Prompt the employee name, hours worked, and the hourly wage.  For each piece of information, you will update the appropriate class member defined above.
    Enter the employee name      = 
    Enter the hours worked       = 
    Enter his or her hourly wage = 

    */

    /*
    Here you will prompt for the third employee’s information.
    Prompt the employee name, hours worked, and the hourly wage.  For each piece of information, you will update the appropriate class member defined above.
    Enter the employee name      = 
    Enter the hours worked       = 
    Enter his or her hourly wage = 

    */

    /*
    Here you will implement a function call to implement the employ calcuations for each object defined above.  You will do this for each of the three employees or objects.
    The format for this step is the following:
     [(object name.function name(objectname.name, objectname.hours, objectname.wage)] ;
    */

    /*
    This section you will send all three objects to a function that will add up the the following information:
    - Total Employee Salaries 
    - Total Employee Hours
    - Total Overtime Hours

    The format for this function is the following:
    - Define a new object.
    - Implement function call [objectname.functionname(object name 1, object name 2, object name 3)]
    /*

    }   //End of Main Function


    void CEmployee::ImplementCalculations (string EmployeeName, double hours, double wage){
    //Initialize overtime variables
    overtime_hours=0;
    overtime_pay=0;
    overtime_extra=0;

     if (hours > 40) 
     {  

    /* 
    This section is for the basic calculations for calculating overtime pay.
    - base pay = 40 hours times the hourly wage
    - overtime hours = hours worked – 40
    - overtime pay = hourly wage * 1.5
    - overtime extra pay over 40 = overtime hours * overtime pay
    - salary = overtime money over 40 hours + your base pay
    */

    /*
    Implement function call to output the employee information.  Function is defined below.
    */


     } // if (hours > 40)
     else
     { 

    /* Here you are going to calculate the hours less than 40 hours.
    - Your base pay is = your hours worked times your wage
    - Salary = your base pay
    */

    /*
    Implement function call to output the employee information.  Function is defined below.
    */

     } // End of the else

    } //End of Primary Function

    void CEmployee::DisplayEmployInformation(); 
    {
    // This function displays all the employee output information.

    /* 
    This is your cout statements to display the employee information:
    Employee Name ............. = 
    Base Pay .................. = 
    Hours in Overtime ......... = 
    Overtime Pay Amount........ = 
    Total Pay ................. = 
    */

    } // END OF Display Employee Information

    void CEmployee::Addsomethingup (CEmployee Employ1, CEmployee  Employ2)
    {
     // Adds two objects of class Employee passed as 
     // function arguments and saves them as the calling object's data member values. 

    /* 
    Add the total hours for objects 1, 2, and 3.
    Add the salaries for each object.
    Add the total overtime hours.
    */

    /*
    Then display the information below.  
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%% EMPLOYEE SUMMARY DATA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%% Total Employee Salaries ..... = 576.43
    %%%% Total Employee Hours ........ = 108
    %%%% Total Overtime Hours......... = 5
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    */
     } // End of function
```

Comment: To format code, select it and use the button with the 101010 pattern in the editor

Comment: can't read that much. please try to narrow your problem definition.

Comment: Well, for starters, using namespace std; should clear you from qualifying your standard library calls with std::. Try to pass objects by const reference instead of by value. That's all the constructive criticism I can give, given that most of the assigment is not even implemented... :)

Comment: I applaud the "I don't want you to do my homework for me" but have zero sympathy on the "it is due tomorrow" comment. You have a large number of comments (which look like they were put their by your educator anyway) and precious little code. My advice, unhelpful though it is to you in the immediate case, is to plan better next time.

Comment: The comments in the code look like they were given to the students, and, oh my, how dreadful. Or perhaps very clever. It's hard to tell. I'm mainly commenting on the data entry, where there's three comments the same. Perhaps the bottom end of the class would copy/paste the code three times whereas the top graders use that well known construct, four letters, sounds like 'soup'.

Comment: @krazywytie Write as much as you can and people will be able to assist you... right now it doesn't look like you've written much code.

Answer (score 3):

**DON'T** use `float`s for financial data, **EVER**.

This will get you into all kinds of rounding and precision problems, and you DON'T want them in data that describes money sums. Unless you like getting sued, of course :).

Either use integer types or create a fixed-point type.

Also, don't use `system()`, if possible. This is inherently non-portable, not to mention being slow and ugly.

Until you fill up more code, this is about all that I can tell you. Good luck!

Comment: I actually consider that float comment as bad advice. Not in general, just the "EVER" bit. It actually requires the adding/subtracting of a *huge* quantity of values for errors to propagate up to the 1/100 fractional place. They propagate faster for multiplication but it's still a lot of operations needed for it to become noticable. And, for homework, there's *nothing* wrong with using floats - as an educator, I'd be pretty suspicious of plagiarism if someone handed in an assignment with a money handling class :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo:
Sir, I don't think you would tolerate ANY error on YOUR payroll :). Money sums have to be kept exact, period. You don't want `0.70+0.10 >= 0.80` to fail, for example. <joke>The IRS may send you to Guantanamo for that.</joke> Also, the number of excess bits in a single-precision float is not that much, especially if the value grows high.
As an educator, **I** would reject any assignment which did something so egregious as keeping a money value in a `float`.
And writing a fixed-point number class is very easy, really.

Comment: I've got to second Slacker here.  I've had a lot of trouble with roundoff errors over the years.  It's very easy to multiply by a large number, then subtract a large number, and get stuck with the roundoff errors.  Higher precision libraries can help somewhat (128/256/512/1024 bit floating point).  But nothing beats good code.  Fixed point is exactly what's needed for money.  (Unless you are tracking fractions of the cents...)

Comment: Slacker makes a good point.  If you find yourself doing intrest calculations which would result in numbers outside of the precision of the number of decimals you have round them down and then transfer the tiny extra bits of money to your own account.

Comment: @slacker, I very much *would* tolerate errors on my payroll, provided they're small enough to not actually affect the results. What I was saying is that, provided you understand how floats work, use of them is fine. *Especially* in a company with only three employees where you're only calculating one weeks wage. This level of classwork does not (in my opinion) need the use of a decimal type. However, I was just pointing out a disagreement with one small part, I didn't feel strongly enough to downvote. I may well have upvoted except for that advice.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback and I know it was a lot to read through. My work schedule makes it tough for me to do these assignments on time, and it's even tougher to procrastinate...grr. let's hope I at least make a C on this assignment so I can get an A overall... Wish me luck!